# Change Tab Programmatically with SlidingTabLayout

Tags: android

I'm using the [SlidingTabLayout](https://developer.android.com/samples/SlidingTabsBasic/src/com.example.android.common/view/SlidingTabLayout.html) example provided by Google.  I'm trying to programmatically switch back to the first tab inside a dialogView that is inside a fragment.

I see a scrollToTab(int tabIndex, int positionOffset).  How can I call this to return to the first tab?

Answer (score 11):

You can use:

```
viewPager.setCurrentItem(itemIndex);
```

viewPager being your view pager for the tabs that you specified in the layout as

`android.support.v4.view.ViewPager`

Comment: Setting tab is ok. I want to change the tab and send some data. How to do it? any Idea?