# How do I programmatically set selected tab SlidingTabLayout

Tags: java, android

Using Google's [SlidingTabLayout](https://developer.android.com/samples/SlidingTabsBasic/src/com.example.android.common/view/SlidingTabLayout.html) how do I programmatically change the selected tab?

Comment: I answered it here:
  http://stackoverflow.com/a/29582101/1869367

Answer (score 1):

```
@Bind(R.id.pager) ViewPager mViewPager;
@Bind(R.id.tabs) SlidingTabLayout tabs;
...
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.activity_team_details);
   ButterKnife.bind(this);

   //get this value from savedInstanceState
   int tabThatNeedsToBeSelected = 3; 

   myFragmentPagerAdapter = new MyFragmentPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(),params);
   mViewPager.setAdapter(myFragmentPagerAdapter);
   tabs.setViewPager(mViewPager);
   mViewPager.setCurrentItem(tabThatNeedsToBeSelected);
}
```